# Sorting pairs of chars to make a path/chain of 'em?

Tags: c#, sorting

i'm making a method for my friend's application, that returns the routes of a vehicle. 
for example, Bus1 has routes A-to-B, B-to-C, C-to-D and in the end there remains a pair whose end is alone just like the first pair's A.

the query is returning the results scrambled since the sequence of routes differs for each vehicle, so i tried to write a method that would sort these combinations to make a path. like a chain. im using chars as locations and strings as routes here.

```
    public void MakePath(ref List<string> routes)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < routes.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < routes.Count; j++)
            {
                if (routes[i][1] == routes[j][0])
                {
                    var temp = routes[i + 1];
                    routes[i + 1] = routes[j];
                    routes[j] = temp;
                    j = routes.Count;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

it works fine in some situations, that is if the last pair is already at its right position.
otherwise it doesn't work, for example

"CD" "AB" "BC"

doesn't work with this. i know it doesn't work because second char of first string is alone as its supposed to be the last pair, so what should i do in this method to take care of the last pair?

Comment: Could you provide the values of the routes list and what you expect as the result?

Comment: its chars like 
string route1 = "CD";
string route2 = "AB"'
string route3 = "BC":

i want output as sorted list, "AB", "BC" , "CD"

Comment: yeah sorry, i pressed enter accidentally.

Comment: Ok. I think the first you need to do is to ensure all the routes are connected. i.e. throw an exception if you have something like "AB" "BC" "DE". Second, knowing all of them are connected, search for endpoint candidates. In you example, if will be D, as there's no such route starting in D. The same for startpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first scan the list and find the terminal stations of the route. In its simplest form this is an algorithm quadratic in the size of the route.

After that you can put the terminal segments of the route in their correct places. After that run your algorithm to "iron" the stuff in-between.

```
public void MakePath(ref List<string> routes)
{
    bool is_first, is_last;
    for (int i = 0; i < routes.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        is_first = true;
        is_last = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < routes.Count; j++)
        {
             if (routes[i][1] == routes[j][0]){
                is_last = false;
                break;
             }
             if (routes[i][0] == routes[j][1]){
                is_start = false;
                break;
             }
        }
        if (is_first) {
             var temp = routes[i];
             routes[i] = routes[0];
             routes[0] = temp;
        }
        if (is_last) {
             var temp = routes[i];
             routes[i] = routes[routes.Count];
             routes[routes.Count] = temp;
        }
     }           
    for (int i = 0; i < routes.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < routes.Count; j++)
        {
            if (routes[i][1] == routes[j][0])
            {
                var temp = routes[i + 1];
                routes[i + 1] = routes[j];
                routes[j] = temp;
                j = routes.Count;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think i get it, but in the code you just put the starting terminal in its position, i need to put the ending one in its right position too, right?

Comment: btw it makes it much more complex, i'll have to iterate 3 nested loops. i wish there was another solution :s

Comment: I have updated the post to sketch how to find the ending terminal in the same loop. Yet the last pair will be put into position by your algorithm, so finding it in the first path is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You need just sort you list before run, than you be sure about start with right route:

```
public void MakePath(ref List<string> routes)
        {
            routes.Sort(); //just insert here
            for (int i = 0; i < routes.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < routes.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (routes[i][1] == routes[j][0])
                    {
                        var temp = routes[i + 1];
                        routes[i + 1] = routes[j];
                        routes[j] = temp;
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: i don't need to sort them alphabetically, the routes could be ZA-AX-XD, i just need to chain them. if i sorted them using list.Sort() it would be, AX-XD-ZA, and that wouldn't work then either.